# .htaccess on filesystem not working

Tags: windows, .htaccess

I tried using a `.htaccess` file on my computer (as in, not on an actual website), but it is not working. I looked for anything relevant, but all I could find were article discussing how Windows doesn't allow a file to be created with a dot as the beginning of the file name. I have made the `.htaccess` file, and am trying to remove the `.html` file endings from the URL:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

However, when I typed the name of the file into the browser bar - without the `.html` extension - I received a 404 error. Why is the `.htaccess` not working on a file system, and how can I make it work?

Comment: Are you using a web server? You need a web server to interpret the .htaccess file (e.g. Apache).

Comment: No, I'm not, it's just a bunch of HTML files sitting on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a web server (e.g. [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/)). The file system or web browser do not know how to interpret the `.htaccess` file, that is done by the web server.